# Which of the following is the correct way to create links for the react components?

Tags: html, reactjs

```
1. <a href={‘https://www.facebook.com/’}>Link1</a>
2. <a link-to={testContainer}>Link1</a>
3. <a href={[to-component]}>Link1</a>
4. <a href-to={‘https://www.facebook.com/’}>Link1</a>
```

Sorry, but I am confused which is the correct answer. Which and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it in your React app. 
It's a correct HTML attribute for React

`<a link-to={testContainer}>Link1</a>`

Answer (score 0):

One of the options not mentioned in your question is using react-router for routing needs. This would involve creating routes which would be later used to navigate the different components. The example below shows a sample Router.

```
      <Router >
        <Route path="/" component={Root}>
          <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
```

You can use the Link object to create dynamic links which would navigate to the appropriate component.Using the above example, this would look like
`<Link to="/home">Home</Link>`

Comment: thanks, but can you recommend an answer number among 1 - 4?